# How to parse only an element in all its children with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using `BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` to parse the HTML page, but it takes too long to parse. 11 seconds.

The HTML document has the following structure

```
<html>
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        <div class="c0">
            <div class="c1"> .... </div>
            <div class="c2"> .... </div>
            <div class="c3"> .... </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I only want to get `<div class="c2">` and ALL its children. The children of `<div class="c2">` can be of any type and class, I want them all.

Is it possible to do with `SoupStrainer` or what ?

If it is not possible to only get `<div class="c2">` and all its children. Just completely NOT parse `<div class="c3">` and its whole tree should work for me.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], as well as the expected result, so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Comment: You can easily extract all elements of a class adding addtional arguments to find_all function n BS4: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all .
`soup.find_all("div", "c2")`

Comment: That is not the point .... I want a way to ignore <div class="c1"> and <div class="c3"> completely so that parsing do not take to long. it is now taking 11 seconds

Comment: Good answers require good and focused questions. So take comments to heart and help us to help you. May take the [tour], read [ask] and add details to improve your questions. Thanks - *but it takes too long to parse. 11 seconds* does not reflect any usable information without a concrete connection to parameters that allow a more precise assessment.

Comment: It is ok if you don't know the answer. Thanks to try.

Answer (score 0):

In your post the statement **`<div class="c2">` and ALL its children** is a bit ambiguous. I assume that you want all contents within the tags `<div class="c2">`.

For a simple html website (saved in the file `website.html`):

```html
<html>
    <head> header </head>
    <body>
        <div class="c0">
            <div class="c1"> <p> Do not parse c1 </p> </div>
            <div class="c2"> 
                <h3> Header in c2 </h3>
                <p> Parse me c2 </p> 
                <table>
                    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="c3"> <p> Do not parse c3 </p> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The starter code could be:

```
import bs4 
with open("website.html") as file:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser') 
    content = soup.find_all("div","c2")
    print(content)
```

The content print would give:

```
[<div class="c2">
<h3> Header in c2 </h3>
<p> Parse me c2 </p>
<table>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
</table>
</div>]
```

Comment: You didn't got the point ... I want to get ride of bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser') .... I want to optimize it

One way could be by replacing html.parse by lxml ... but I would like to know if there is something else